# Cross Apply in SQL server 2017

Tags: sql-server

i am trying to split String into multiple row using cross apply 
is it possible to use the cross apply in SQL server 2017?
how to replace cross apply?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but you probably want to look at [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

Comment: Yes, cross apply works in SQL Server 2017. Can you please post some example data and what you expect your results to be. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @ twoleggedhorse  i already split string by using SQL server 2008 but while using SQL server 2017 i was  quite confuse ,is it possible to use cross apply  or not but now i got a answer.thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string_split()` and `apply`:

```
select . . .
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.col, ',');
```